# Is it recommended to convert code in existing posts to stack snippets?

Tags: discussion, stack-snippets

The recently new Stack Exchange feature [Stack Snippets](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2014/09/introducing-runnable-javascript-css-and-html-code-snippets/) is recommended to use for new posts.

Is it allowed and recommended for existing posts too?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It's allowed, but I personally wouldn't recommend it.

If you come across a post and it requires **other** edits then you might as well convert the code samples to snippets. However, if it's the *only* thing you are doing or you are just looking for posts to convert then you're probably doing it wrong.

See my answers on Stack Overflow for my thoughts on this:

> [Should we edit our old posts to include Stack Snippets?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/271506/should-we-edit-our-old-posts-to-include-stack-snippets/271507#271507)
>
> [Suggested Edit Replacing JSFiddle with Stack Snippet, what to do?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/271589/suggested-edit-replacing-jsfiddle-with-stack-snippet-what-to-do/271597#271597)